# AWS Lambda is getting timed out while downloading the VGG16 imagenet model data

Tags: keras, deep-learning, aws-lambda

We have a lambda function where we will use Keras to extract features from images. So, when the lambda function is trying to download the VGG16 imagenet model, there it is getting timed out.

Code where lambda is getting timed out:-

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
```

How to solve this issue ? Can we login to the backend container of a lambda function and download the model ?

Lambda code:-

```
import os
import shutil
import stat
import zipfile
import boto3
from six.moves import urllib


s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def download(url, local_fpath):
    print('downloading other files........')
    s3.download_file('HARDCODED_BUCKET', url,local_fpath)

def make_gcc_executable():
    for fpath in os.listdir("/tmp/gcc/bin"):
        fpath = os.path.join("/tmp/gcc/bin", fpath)
        st = os.stat(fpath)
        os.chmod(fpath, st.st_mode | stat.S_IXOTH | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXUSR)

    for fpath in os.listdir("/tmp/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.4"):
        fpath = os.path.join("/tmp/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.4", fpath)
        st = os.stat(fpath)
        os.chmod(fpath, st.st_mode | stat.S_IXOTH | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXUSR)

# Download GCC and uncompress it.
download('test/imglib-new/gcc.zip', "/tmp/gcc.zip")
zipfile.ZipFile("/tmp/gcc.zip").extractall("/tmp/gcc")

make_gcc_executable()



from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import numpy as np

def _get_model2():
    print('downloadin our model....')
    s3.download_file('BUCKET','test/model/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5','/tmp/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')

    #model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    print('model download is done')
    model = VGG16(weights='/tmp/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5')
    return model

model = _get_model2()



def handler(event, context):
    print('entering the function..downloading the images')
    download_loc='/tmp/dog2.jpg'
    s3.download_file('BUCKET', 'test/images/dog2.jpg',download_loc)
    print('image is downloaded')



    print('running the model now..')

    img = image.load_img(download_loc, target_size=(224, 224))
    img_data = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_data = np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=0)
    img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)
    print('extracting the feature...')
    vgg16_feature = model.predict(img_data)
    print('over..')
    print(vgg16_feature.shape)
```

Error message:-

```
START RequestId: 00827d13-d7a4-11e8-9ea2-c5365d4fbfcb Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: Compilation failed (return status=1): /tmp/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.14-amzn1.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5-x86_64-3.6.1-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory. compilation terminated.. 

END RequestId: 00827d13-d7a4-11e8-9ea2-c5365d4fbfcb
REPORT RequestId: 00827d13-d7a4-11e8-9ea2-c5365d4fbfcb  Duration: 153.15 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 832 MB Max Memory Used: 225 MB 
module initialization error
Compilation failed (return status=1): /tmp/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.14-amzn1.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5-x86_64-3.6.1-64/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory. compilation terminated..
```

Comment: Hello,

Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda does not give you access to log-in to the the container. You haven't mentioned the size of the model, but you have some options:

- A lambda deployment can be up to 50mb, so you may well be able to upload the model as part of your code package and save yourself downloading it.
- If you *have* to download the model, up your timeout to the full 15 minutes. It's unlikely that any file that takes more time than that to download would even fit in a lambda's RAM in any case.
- Consider the source of your download. S3 to Lambda downloads at 50mb/s, so uploading your model to S3 would give you better speed on larger downloads.
- Make sure you do the download out of the scope of the handler function- that way you'll only spend the time download the model when your lambda's container loads for the first time.

Comment: The model size is ~500MB.

Comment: So, Basically what I did is copied a model of size ~50MB to S3 and then downloaded from s3 to my lambda. In this case also the code is stuck when it starts running VGG16(..). I don't know why it is not running. Could it be that I haven't installed gcc there ?

Comment: Can you upload the complete lambda code? Or confirm with printing logs either side that it's the line `model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)` where your code is halting? If there was just an error then the lambda would exit immediately; timing out suggests that your code is doing something which is either not completing in time (what's your timeout- have you tried the full 15 minutes?) or stuck in a loop.

Comment: Added the lambda code and also with gcc, the compilation error I am getting

Comment: OK- so you're lamba's not timing out (it completes after 150ms) the problem is that your lambda package does not have the header files needed (in this case Python.h - although I suspect there'll be more as you solve them.) Ideally you'd use a compiled version, or package the headers you need in your deployment.